# User input text from react-select component call onchange

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to use `react-select` as an input.

When user types, it will autocomplete the options that already exists, but if none exists, keep the text value and call `onChange` when I blur the component or press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

I know about `Creatable`, but I don't need to create a new option, just save the value the user wrote.